# io.flutter.facade.flutter not found in flutter aar

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter

1. I have built aar from flutter module by `flutter build aar --no-profile --no-release`
2. and I have added aar in existing android studio project
3. In activity I am trying to launch flutter as below

   `FlutterView flutterView = Flutter.createView(MainActivity.this, getLifecycle(), null);`

But build is failing with

```
 error: package io.flutter.facade is not existed
 import io.flutter.facade.Flutter;
```

any help?